# How can i make MongoDB safe from other users?

Tags: python, mongodb

I've heard that MongoDB is very good Database, especially for placing large data inside, However i'm not sure how safe can it really be.

I'm not experienced at MongoDB, but before i choose, i want to know how safe it can be for important data.

So for example, if i specified uri, i would type this:

```
uri = "mongodb://test1:test1@ds051990.mongolab.com:51990/base1"
```

I'm trying to make a P2P text chat, It can be accessed on user's PC with root permissions, Whenever user registers, User's Latest IP, Username and will be added to database, as code was shown below.

But the "Hacker" would easily access it by simply getting into code, and viewing all the information, then he would read/write all the data inside.

What would be the best solution to prevent this issue? I think high-level Databases like MongoDB would have some-kind of protection against other users accessing it.

How can make sure only necessary users can access database and other users can't enter it by viewing uri variable?

If not is there ANY other way i can do it? So user can't access Database at all, But i would read and write files from database.

Comment: Are you really talking about allowing access straight to the db from your client computers? That sounds like a very bad idea.

Comment: Is there any other safe way? like creating a user to database with minimal permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You have no easy way of hiding the credentials. Instead, create a user with the minimal required permissions in the database, and use these credentials in your distributed code.

If you are worried about the users being able to see plain-text IP addresses, you should hash and salt them before inserting them to the database.

Comment: so as example, can i create a user account, that will have permission to access specific file only? (read/write)

Comment: @ShellRox see the docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/

Comment: but how would i create a user, from code, without using admin permissions?